# Dll Delphi Usando no C#

Tags: c#, delphi

Ola, estou tentando integrar uma dll feita em delphi 10.1 e usar as funções dela em C# porem ela ate acessa a dll porem o aplicativo FECHA sem dar erro nenhum, vou passar como estou fazendo.

```
[DllImport("Func.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]

public static extern string TestePAnsiChar();
```

Essa Função teste me retorna uma string "Dll Carregada!"

Essa função em delphi :

`function TestePAnsiChar: PAnsiChar; stdcall; begin try Result := 'Dll Carregada!'; except on e: exception do Result := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(e.Message)); end; end;`

Acredito que o problema seja o tipo em c# porque mudei essa função para retornar um INT e ai da certo, só não da certo com esse tipo PAnsiChar.
Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Obrigado pela ajuda mas consegui resolver o problema da seguinte forma no código em c# ficou assim :

```
[DllImport("Func.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern IntPtr Configura([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)] string cEmp);
```

A função em delphi não mudei nada e a parte do c# ficou assim :

```
                IntPtr str = Configura("01");
            string teste = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(str);
```

Obrigado e ate mais.